# update or delete on table "genero" violates foreign key constraint "fk_genero_filme" on table "filme"

Tags: postgresql

I need to delete a genre of genero table using a function. But when I create the function and run "select * from delet", displays the message:

```
ERROR: update or delete on table "genero" violates foreign key constraint "fk_genero_filme" on table "filme"
DETAIL: Key (id) = (1) is still referenced from table "movie".
```

My table structure:

```
create table genero(
    id numeric(5) not null,
    nome varchar(100), 
    constraint genero_pkey primary key (id)
);

create table filme(
    id numeric(5) not null,
    nome varchar(100),
    duracao varchar(100),
    sinopse varchar(2000),
    genero numeric(5),
    data timestamp, 
    constraint pk_genero primary key (id), 
    constraint fk_genero_filme foreign key (genero) references genero (id)
);
```

The delete function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delet (id numeric(5))
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM genero;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Function call:

```
Select delet(6);
```

Comment: Please show your database structure, data example and the full SQL query. Also, please use code formatting.

Comment: create table genero( 
id numeric(5) not null,nome varchar(100), 
constraint genero_pkey primary key (id) 
);create table filme( 
id numeric(5) not null, nome varchar(100), duracao varchar(100), 
sinopse varchar(2000),genero numeric(5),data timestamp, 
constraint pk_genero primary key (id), 
constraint fk_genero_filme foreign key (genero) references genero (id) 
);CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delet (id numeric(5)) RETURNS VOID AS   $$ 
          BEGIN 
            DELETE FROM genero;END;$$ 
      LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE 
      COST 100;Select delet(6);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are some issues with the code.

First of all, the delet function deletes ALL rows as you have no WHERE clause. It should be more like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delet(_id numeric)
    RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM genero WHERE id = _id;
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Secondly, the `fk_genero_filme` constraint (as reported in the error) has default behavior - NO ACTION. This means that if you have at least one film referencing a genre, this particular genre can not be removed. If you expected that DELETE on genre will also remove all films in this genre you should use ON DELETE CASCADE:

```
ALTER TABLE filme
    DROP CONSTRAINT fk_genero_filme;
ALTER TABLE filme
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_genero_filme
        FOREIGN KEY (genero)
        REFERENCES genero (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And finally, you should define IDs as integer instead of numeric for performance reasons.